# Let Y be the number of heads and Z the number of tails, find $P \{X \leq x\}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Three coins are tossed. Let Y be the number of heads and Z the number of tails. For each of the following random variables find $P \{X \leq x\}$

a.) $X=Y-Z$

b.)$X= max\{Y,Z\}$

c.)$X=\left |Y-Z  \right |$

I can't understand what I want, help me with a hint

Comment: What is an "uncharged coin"?

Comment: You have $Y+Z=3$, so each of your cases can be rewritten in terms of Y or Z

Comment: You have $Y+Z=3$, so each of your cases can be rewritten in terms of Y or Z

Comment: uncharged coin has 2 sides that are equally likely to land when tossed the coin.

Answer (score 0):

Well $P\{X\leq x\}$ is [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $F_X(x)$. This function is like

> Let's take some $x$. Then what is the probability that the random variable $X$ will be less than $x$.

This $x$ may have **any** value and is **not** required $x\in X$.

As Gono said, $Y+Z=3$, so assume $Y=3-Z$.

a) $X=Y-Z=3-Z-Z=3-2Z=\{-3;-1;1;3\}$ - all possible values of $X$ when $Z=3,2,1$ and $0$.

Now let's calculate probabilities of these values:
$$P(-3)=P(3)=0.5^3=0.125\\
P(-1)=P(1)=0.5^3*3=0.375$$
We definitely can say that $P(X\leq -10)=0$ or $P(X\leq -5)=0$ because min value of $X$ is $-3$ and there is no single chance that X will be less than $-10$ or $-5$. Same for $P(X\leq 10)=1$ because max value of $X$ is $3$.

What if $x=-2$? There is only one value exists, that less than $-2$. It's $-3$. And the probability that the random variable $X$ takes a value of $-3$ is $0.125$.

Fine. But what if $x=-0.5$? $X$ might be less or equal than $-0.5$ when it's value is $-3$ or $-1$. Then $P(X\leq -0.5)=P(-3)+P(-1)=0.5$*. Sounds logical, especially if we took $x=0$, because intuition (and expected value $E[X]$) suggests that on average $Y-Z=0$.

**I don't know how "$P(A+B)=P(A)+P(B)$" property will be in English, but this is our case because if $X=-3$ it can't be equal to $-1$ at the same time.*

Now, after the examples above, it should become easy to define the entire cumulative distribution function, so that I will omit further reasoning.
$$P\{X\leq x\}=F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0,  & x\lt -3 \\
P(-3)=0.125, & -3\leq x\lt -1 \\
P(-3)+P(-1)=0.5, & -1\leq x\lt 1 \\
P(-3)+P(-1)+P(1)=0.875, & 1\leq x\lt 3 \\
P(-3)+P(-1)+P(1)+P(3)=1, & 3\leq x
\end{cases}\\$$
b) $$X=max\{Y,Z\}=max\{3-Z,Z\}=\{2,3\}\\
P(2)=0.75\\
P(3)=0.25\\
P\{X\leq x\}=F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0,  & x\lt 2 \\
0.75, & 2\leq x\lt 3 \\
1, & 3\leq x \\
\end{cases}\\$$
c) $$X=|Y-Z|=|3-Z-Z|=|3-2Z|=\{1,3\}\\
P(1)=0.75\\
P(3)=0.25\\
P\{X\leq x\}=F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0,  & x\lt 1 \\
0.75, & 1\leq x\lt 3 \\
1, & 3\leq x \\
\end{cases}\\$$
Ask if there are any more questions left.

Comment: thanks! I had already raised it by making tables of each case but as you explain it, it is faster!